# How to get ttf from external domain without CORS problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tomcat, cors

I'm trying to get a .ttf to use in my web application from an external website. When I try it in this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font';
  src: url('http://xxx.xyz/resources/tipografias/font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I'm getting a CORS problem because of:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have tried with the jQuery showed by this website: [Html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

I have tried also with tomcat filters for CORS: [CORS filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)

And I have tries it with javascript too: [Javascript](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_cors.htm)

I don't know what I'm doing bad

Comment: If you don't have control over that domain, then you cannot. I'd suggest downloading the TTF file (assuming you have the rights to it) and then include it locally on your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the external website and use `htaccess` you can use the following code to allow other websites to load your fonts:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you don't control the external website it's not possible to bypass the `CORS` policy.

---

I believe the following should work in your `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have control on the external website. Where must I place those code lines?

Comment: In an `.htaccess` file in the root of the website or some subdirectory that includes the font file @DMC19.

Comment: I'm researching how to do the same as you propose in my web.xml, because I don't have .htaccess file and I have to configure it in web.xml

Comment: Check out my edit @DMC19; I believe it should work for you.

Comment: I have allowed access in the external web and all works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass this - the server doesn't want you to have access to the font. As others have said, you **could** just download the font file and serve it locally. But that would likely be considered **stealing**. Depending on the font, it may be a specially licensed one.

If this is a 'font factory' (a company that designs and licenses fonts), then they likely will only allow licensed sites to access the font file (by checking whether the Origin request header your browser sends is on their list of allowed sites).

Side-note - CORS was basically invented specifically to stop people downloading fonts from font factories.